# How do I make my own function to insert text in vim?

Tags: command-line, vimrc

I have a folder of third party libraries called `add-libraries` and the location for this specific library is `/home/yapjiahong/projects/cpp/add-libraries/plog/include`.

I want to write a function called `Include` that takes in `lib` as an argument. Then append that to the end of a string. Then write it out where my cursor is at this is what I currently have:

```
function Include(lib)
    let path = "/home/yapjiahong/projects/cpp/add-libraries/" . a:lib
    exe "insert!: . l:path
endfunction
```

This gives an error and I'm not too sure how to fix it. This alternatives works, but I wanna use a function instead. The alternative:

```
nnoremap <leader>ff i/home/yapjiahong/projects/cpp/add-libraries/<Esc><Esc>
```

Comment: Are you looking for the :map command?

Comment: I know :map just lets me remap a command to a preferred keybinding. But I'm trying to make my own command.

Comment: I'm afraid you don't know map. Have a look at eg. https://vim.fandom.com/wiki/Mapping_keys_in_Vim_-_Tutorial_(Part_1). I spent half my life using vi and wouldn't pretend to know it.

Comment: Well I've read up on it. Turns out you can do much more. And I figured a few things out. But I keep getting the same error. Trailing characters. [This](https://paste.rs/3kh) is what I currently have.

Comment: How did you map the Inc function?

Comment: Welcome to [vi.se]! Can you please expand on what you're trying to accomplish? You mentioned "snippets" but didn't really explain them, are these stored as files that you want to read from the include directory? Can you give an example of file you would have there and what the end result you'd like? Thanks!

Comment: Sorry for the late replies. @Gerard I didn't I ended up doing [this](https://paste.rs/xg4) instead. Because I still can't figure out how to use functions properly.

Answer (score 2):

The `:insert` command cannot take an argument like you're trying to do, it expects user input for the lines, followed by a single line consisting of a `.` to finish inserting.

You probably want the `append()` function instead:

```
function Include(lib)
    let path = "/home/yapjiahong/projects/cpp/add-libraries/" . a:lib
    call append(line('.') - 1, path)
endfunction
```

Answer (score 0):

I think what you want is an [abbreviation](https://vimhelp.org/map.txt.html#abbreviations) when you are in insert mode.  Try adding the following to your .vim/ftplugin/cpp.vim file:

```
iabbr <buffer> include() /home/yapjiahong/projects/cpp/add-libraries/plog/include
```

Now, whenever you are in insert mode and type `include()` followed by a space or return, the text on the right hand side will automatically replace the text on the lefthand side.

Note:  I couldn't get the abbreviation to work with a `:` in the front.

I hope that helps and is what you were looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Try defining in your vimrc:

`:command! Include call Ins()<CR>`

And define your function in your vimrc(it is referenced in the comments).

Then use `:Include` to execute.